# Why using DELETE key followed by selection of vertices from the mirrored side sometimes also deleted some horizontal edges of the original side?

Tags: vertices, mirror

at the initial stage when there was only the default cube, I went to the Tool icon on the right of the screen and clicked Y in Options's Mirror. I then made things for the left hand side using E and CTRL-R. Automatically, Blender created the vertices, edges and a silhouette on the right hand side for me. Here is the problem. When I highlighted the entire right hand side with the mouse and pressed DELETE and chose Vertices, some of the horizontal edges on the left hand side also got deleted. If I highlighted fewer individual vertices (say 1-3) and the connected edges on the right, sometimes only those vertices and edges joining them got deleted but sometimes corresponding edge(s) on the left also got deleted. What is wrong here? How can I prevent horizontal edges on the left got automatically deleted?

Comment: You need to uncheck the Y in the Option Mirror setting if you don't want both sides to be deleted. Also, you may only be selecting the front vertices for deleting if you aren't in x-ray mode (Alt-Z). To be honest I never normally use the options mirror, preferring to use a mirror modifier.

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between options mirror and mirror modifier?

Comment: These are the Blender manual descriptions for [Options Mirror](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/meshes/tools/tool_settings.html?utm_source=blender-3.6.4#mirror) and [Mirror Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html#mirror-modifier).  See the Note section for the Mirror option!  Quick tip: To easily look up the Blender manual entry of a particular option, right-click on it and choose "Online Manual" from the popup menu.